# Using generalized components in React

Tags: reactjs

Say I wanted a generalized component for a dropdown like so:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function DropDown() {
    const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    const clickHandler = () => {
        setMenuOpen(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setMenuOpen(false);
        }, 2000);

        props.onClick();
    }

    return (
        <p>Dropdown</p>
        {menuOpen && <p>{props.text}</p>}
    )
}
```

I want to then be able to use this dropdown for several components (e.g. a save button, switch between light and dark modes, etc.).

Here's a sample save button:

```js
import React from "react";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

export default function SaveButton() {
    return (
        <DropDown text="Save" onClick={() => console.log("Saved")}
    )
}
```

For the light and dark mode button, I would want to `console.log` whether we're currently on light or dark mode.

```js
import React from "react";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

export default function LightDark() {
    return (
        <DropDown text="Save" onClick={() => console.log(menuOpen ? "light" : "dark")}
    ) // Don't have access to menuOpen
}
```

I know this is a simple example (the actual code I'm working on involves more complicated casework). But what's the best way to deal with a situation like this, *where I want to combine functionality into a general component, but the individual components differ enough that it may be difficult?* Here are some of my thoughts: to use casework in generalized component (Case 1), to handle it within the save button or light/dark mode component (Case 2)? Or perhaps another solution?

Case 1 Example:
// DropDown.js

```js
const clickHandler = () => {
    setMenuOpen(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
        setMenuOpen(false);
    }, 2000);

    if (props.text === "Save") {
        // Blah
    } else {
        // Blah
    } // Although this doesn't seem like a good solution for more complicated cases where this generalized component may be used a lot
}
```

Case 2 Example:
// LightDark.js

```js
import React from "react";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

export default function LightDark() {
    return (
        <DropDown text="Save" onClick={(menuOpen) => console.log(menuOpen ? "light" : "dark")} // menuOpen passed from higher order component, also doesn't feel like a good solution when things get complicated
    ) 
}
```

It may be worth noting that I would like to use functional components.

Comment: Your aim isn't entirely clear and there are a couple of syntax errors in the code pieces you provided. I suggest stating a clear objective and providing an executable code snippet of the problem you're facing.

Comment: @tgikf The code I provided above is merely a trivial example I came up with that conveys the underlying question: When using a generalized component, where should I handle differences in functionality? Handling it in the generalized component may violate Separation of concerns while handling it in the individual component will limit access to variables declared in the generalized component.

Comment: If you want to reuse the component, you will always have to abstract its logic into the parent component, which means you won't have any "variable access" beyond the props/states. Otherwise (e.g., your case 1 example), you're introducing dependencies between your component and the rest of your code base you don't want. See Specialization on https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks. I ended up implemented something similar to what the docs called `Specialization`

Answer (score 1):

I understood you want to create a UI component that provides some sort of context menu and can be reused for different actions (e.g. changing the theme, saving/discarding content). Provided my interpretation is correct, the example below might help you to achieve what you want.

Some additional remarks:

- I suggest being careful with the term Dropdown in this context as what you're looking for IMO is closer to a context menu
- To store the theme (or any value that should be globally available across your app), you'd want to use a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) rather than a state.
- Once you have a good overview over the use cases you'd want to use this component for, you should review the case for re-use and weigh its benefits against the complexity it forces you to introduce

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const ThemeContext = React.createContext("dark");

const CustomMenu = (props) => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleLabelClick = () => {
    setMenuOpen(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMenuOpen(false);
    }, 2000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleLabelClick}> {props.label} </button>
      {menuOpen &&
        props.options.map((e) => <p onClick={e.action}> {e.label} </p>)}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Theme changed to ${theme}`);
  }, [theme]);
  
  const themeOptions = [
    {
      label: "light",
      action: () => setTheme("light"),
    },
    {
      label: "dark",
      action: () => setTheme("dark"),
    },
  ];
  
  const saveOptions = [
    {
      label: "save",
      action: () => console.log("saved"),
    },
    {
      label: "discard",
      action: () => console.log("discarded"),
    },
  ];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomMenu label="Select Theme" options={themeOptions} />
      <CustomMenu label="Action" options={saveOptions} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```